# Why isn't my code working to make datetime objects timezone-aware?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone

I have two python datetime objects that represent the same moment in time:

```
a = datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 13, 26, 30)
b = datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 7, 26, 30)
```

Both are coming from different sources.
I know that the first is in UTC, and the second is in `"America/Edmonton"` (MDT).
Neither initially have a timezone attached to them.

I need to add timezones to these objects and compare them in a way where `a == b` is `True`.

What I did was this:

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone

a = datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 13, 26, 30)
b = datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 7, 26, 30)

a = a.replace(tzinfo=timezone("UTC"))
b = b.replace(tzinfo=timezone("America/Edmonton"))

a = a.astimezone(timezone("America/Edmonton"))
b = b.astimezone(timezone("America/Edmonton"))

print(repr(a))
# Result: datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 7, 26, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Edmonton' MDT-1 day, 18:00:00 DST>)

print(repr(b))
# Result: datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 7, 26, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Edmonton' LMT-1 day, 16:26:00 STD>)

a == b # Results in False for some reason
```

What is `"MDT-1 day, 18:00:00 DST"` vs `"LMT-1 day, 16:26:00 STD"`? Why are they different? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mountain Daylight Time https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/mdt & Local Mean Time https://www.timeanddate.com/time/local-mean-time.html. I think you can just do `b.astimezone(timezone('UTC'))` & compare them in utc instead of converting a & b

Comment: That doesn't appear to work either. `a != b` still

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this appears to be:

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone

a = datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 13, 26, 30)
b = datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 7, 26, 30)

a = timezone('UTC').localize(a)
b = timezone('America/Edmonton').localize(b)

a == b
```

As demonstrated [here](http://blog.qax.io/pytz-and-strange-timezones/). This does result in `a` being equal to `b`. Still not sure why it sounds like pytz is defaulting to using a system from before 1893.